# Overlapping Elements in React Native: Avoiding External Libraries

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, view

I want to clarify that I prefer not to use any external libraries for this issue.
The problem I'm encountering is with overlapping elements, as illustrated in the screenshots below:

[image: image with overlapping element]

[image: image with overlapping element]

I have a **CustomerMenuPopUpSeeMore** component that consists of multiple TouchableOpacity elements within a View. This component is used inside another component, and when I open the menu for a specific card, the elements overlap.

Here is the CustomerMenuPopUpSeeMore component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const CustomerMenuPopUpSeeMore = ({ id, onDelete }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.itemsContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => onDelete(id)}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>Delete</Text>
          <AntDesign name="delete" color={"white"} size={20} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>SMS</Text>
          <AntDesign name="message1" color={"white"} size={20} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>Email</Text>
          <AntDesign name="mail" color={"white"} size={20} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    overflow: 'visible',
  },
  label: {
    color: "white",
  },
  itemsContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
    borderRadius: 5,
    minWidth: 130,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: 'red',
    overflow: 'visible',
  },
  item: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 15,
  },
});

export default CustomerMenuPopUpSeeMore;
```

The **CustomerMenuPopUpSeeMore** is then used as follows:

```
{openMenuId === customer.id && (
  <View style={styles.menu}>
    <CustomerMenuPopUpSeeMore
      id={customer.id}
      onDelete={handleDelete}
    />
  </View>
)}
```

And the styling for the menu container is:

```
menu: {
  position: "absolute",
  top: 11,
  right: 55,
  zIndex: 100
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using flatlist for rendering the above items, the behavior for zIndex is different for flatlists, you can check [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28751#issuecomment-619359762).
You just need to add a zIndex style to your PopUp component and make it very high. it should resolve your problem.

Comment: setting the zIndex to a very large value solved the problem. this is the value i set     zIndex: 10000000000,
hoping this will help someone. thank you very much